# How to display an optimzed Route (Waypoint Sequence) in a Map? Here Technologies

Tags: here-api, here-tourplanning

I am using Here Technologies to optimize Routes in an Angular Application. After optimizing I'd like to display the new Route. Is there a way to display a route on a map in the Angular Application?

Comment: Can you specify which HERE APIs or SDKs you use?

Comment: @Datasun Sure, I am using the Waypoint Sequence API.

Answer (score 0):

If you’ve read the official documentation for the HERE API with JavaScript, the above line might look loosely familiar. Basically it is going to act as a container for the map component. However, we are no longer working with an id and instead are working with a #map. The #map acts as an Angular template variable which is more appropriate when trying to work directly with the DOM rather than using data bindings.

Now open the project’s src/app/app.component.ts file so we can add our TypeScript logic that performs the bulk of our work:

```
    import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

declare var H: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    title = 'here-project';
    private platform: any;

    @ViewChild("map")
    public mapElement: ElementRef;

    public constructor() {
        this.platform = new H.service.Platform({
            "apikey": "API_KEY"
        });
    }

    public ngOnInit() { }

    public ngAfterViewInit() {
        let defaultLayers = this.platform.createDefaultLayers();
        let map = new H.Map(
            this.mapElement.nativeElement,
            defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,
            {
                zoom: 10,
                center: { lat: 37.7397, lng: -121.4252 }
            }
        );
    }

}
```

For more info please check this [link](https://developer.here.com/blog/display-here-maps-angular-web-application)

You can also check the official [document](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.30.3/dev_guide/topics/angular-practices.html) for set up as well